# Are javascript functions safe from being called from outside the writen script?

Tags: php, javascript, security, optimization

In my travels I had ran across some url hacks and looking at some of the dev tools in the few browsers I've had time to look at brings me to ask this Q.

Is there  hacks or tools that will strip out scripted javascript functions and/or allow a user to populate the arguments their self's and run the functions?

Now of course I don't mean the obvious security hole that register globals makes if you dont filter the global always; nor do I mean the form injection hacks basically.

I do use a lot of xmlhttprequest  posts and delimited strings while using php preg_match for basic characters that is different for each different post var before any input hits the server script. Register Globals -> Off. However I guess I am looking for things I can adjust certain functions to be safer for me.

IE.. I dont want the functions be called 1000 times in a row as fast as the tool can dish, but I don't want to waste the resources if certain things are safe.

Not only am I asking this for security reasons but for size and optimizing reasons as well.

I'm thinking that a packet sniffer/interseptor/sender may be able to but I'm not 100% sure. Also, I am not sure the need would be so great as to go to the lengths to count the calls that may affect the server performance if it cant be done. IE.. monitor on the server the xmlhttprequests.

////////////// Edit //////////

For reference, a tool I had just ran across, a .htaccess file has the ability to redirect by what is in the query. I guess it is not fool proof and is just one tool of many. however it can protect against url atacks. It seems to me that it can reduce the load by redirection when apache calls the .htaccess file stopping the most loading on a successful catch. http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects.

Comment: Even outside of a browser, people can make requests to your server at high frequencies. I believe it's called a Denial of Service attack if they can crash your server because of so many requests. You'll have to configure/throttle requests at your server. You'd probably want to do this early in the process so it doesn't get deep in your server code and can back things up

Comment: I can look at the source of a page, see the php function being called by the URL and the data sent with it (either POST or GET) and then make a page that calls it infinitely myself.  Always assume any exposed javascript/PHP function can and will be brutally called by someone malicious.

Comment: Just protect your backend, client is out of your control.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense to me. JavaScript is on the client so you cannot control it.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to prevent something like this: http://puu.sh/3l75C.png

Comment: I think to protect  your website from abused calls, you can store the IP and calculate the number of calls per minute for example,then banned who exceeds a certain fixed number.

Comment: Timmz. Right.  Do you think it'd be worth doing compared to the alternative risk?

Comment: mb21. IE. Javascript. Xmlhttprequest will allow you to pass post or get vars.  So technically it can control server scripting by calling a script page passing vars to it.

Comment: BlargleMonster. Sure. Its my site in my profile.

Comment: Ian. Yes. However, could someone abusing functions on the client cause noticeable harm/affect if the functions control pages/applications running server script? Maybe if the script is a little heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing you need to ask your self is: where is the attacker and what is the attack surface? The user is always able access to all JavaScript, and he is free to manipulate this JavaScript however he pleases ([SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey)). A user is free to intercept **any** HTTP request and modify this request however they would like ([burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)).  A JavaScript function running on the browser is in no way, shape, or form an attack surface, and it never will be. **No one cares who is invoking a JS function, because this is simply not an abuseable condition.**

The real security question you need to ask your self is: "Is your application vulnerable to [Cross-Site Scripting?](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)"

Comment: My site is pretty bulky and I am almost ready to downsize so it is slower than most.  As I have it is always good to look, ask and implement before its too late.

Comment: @JSG Study complexity theory and use a pofiler.  Changing how a function is invoked will not affect the complexity of an operation.